# One to One Relationship Suggestion

Tags: laravel

One Job has Many InventoryJobs

One InventoryJob has one SubJob

But

I was thinking of defining it as One SubJob has One InventoryJob because in that case

inventoryjobs table will have the sub_job_id column

InventoryJobs are rarely created

Am i correct?

Comment: What you are saying is totally unclear. What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are wondering if the foreign key that links `InventoryJob` and `SubJob` should be on `InventoryJob` pointing to `Subjob` or on `Subjob` pointing to `InventoryJob` considering that the relationship is 1-1 and `InventoryJob` is rarely created.

I think it will make no difference. The realtionship is 1-1, there is no way of creating a `SubJob` without creating an `InventoryJob` or the other way around so they will be created as rarely. I think it doesn't matter.